# Landsat 8 new L1TP data metadata MtL can not be read in PCI geomatics

Tags: landsat

How do I use pic.fimport to open a Landsat 8 metadata MTL?
I do not know why fimport cannot read the new MTL txt file.

Comment: What do you mean "can not read"? What error message(s) or undesirable behavior do you get?

Answer (score 0):

When use fimport to read the MTL.txt
I add ms in end of the file name 
But it says file does not exit 
Either with or without ms , it says file does not exist